# iis 8 basic authentication 404 error

Tags: windows, http-status-code-404, iis-8, http-basic-authentication

I deployed a .Net application on `Windows Server 2012`. The application works fine when no authentication is enabled(with anonymous authentication). When I enable Basic authentication, the site redirects to some Accounts/login*** page(having set proper `Default Document`).

The issue is similar to the one in the link http://forums.iis.net/t/1228477.aspx?Basic+Authentication+in+IIS8. I tried the following settings in web.config file but no luck.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>

<appSettings>
  <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
</appSettings>
```

Anybody came across this and know how to fix it?. Any help is appreciated!.

Comment: I'm unable to figure this out myself, but still trying...

Comment: What are the 404 sub-status and win32 status codes from the IIS log?

Comment: Here is my IIS logs http://pastebin.com/pHfztLgY

Comment: What type of .NET app? Provided web.config shows you're using Windows auth not Basic. Make sure your code isn't inadvertently using Forms Auth and that your users have the necessary permissions to read the content.

Comment: Have you installed Basic Authentication through Install Server Roles?

Comment: Basic Authentication is not installed by default and once it is installed it defaults to disabled. See: [Basic Authentication <basicAuthentication>](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/basicauthentication)